Sum of text Does not contain in Range
Hi I have a data of more than 15K rows.
I want to take sum of items which are in the list and also sum of items which are does not in the list.
I am getting result with the textsplit function when it is includes with the range.
below is my formula:
=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT(F2,",")=B2:B12)*C2:C12)

If I am using the same formula for "Not Equals to" it is not giving the exact result.
I stuck here what could be the reason.
=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT(F2,",")<>B2:B12)*C2:C12)

but some how I managed my work with Filter function.
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C12,(B2:B12<>"A")*(B2:B12<>"D")*(B2:B12<>"E")*(B2:B12<>"H")*(B2:B12<>"K")))

Anyone could help why the Textsplit function is not giving exact result when I am using "Not equals to"
Thank you :-)


Because it tests the list of items against the criteria in F2 or F5 one letter at a time. There is only one row that is =A, but 10 rows that are <>A.

…  Why not just add everything, and then subtract the "include" version?

Another alternative way and yes it should be 10 and not 13 when it is not equal to the split value of A,D,E,H,K


=LET(
 a, TEXTSPLIT(E2,","),
 SUM(FILTER(C$2:C$12,MMULT(N(a=B$2:B$12),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a))^0)=0)))


To get the reverse that equals to then :
=LET(
 a, TEXTSPLIT(E2,","),
 SUM(FILTER(C$2:C$12,MMULT(N(a=B$2:B$12),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a),,,0))>0)))


Per OP:

Thank you @Mayukh, Just consider A=1,B=1,C=1....K=1. A,D,E,H,K
includes result 5 and B,C,F,G,I,J does not includes result 6. I hope
this will give clear result. –  Srikanth


The given formula is correctly working without any issues, please try to test on your end, the following screenshot demonstrates that :


We can exclude the FILTER() function:
=LET(
     a,TEXTSPLIT(E2,","),
     SUM((MMULT(N(a=B$2:B$12),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a),,,0))>0)*C$2:C$12))


And
=LET(
     a,TEXTSPLIT(E2,","),
     SUM((MMULT(N(a=B$2:B$12),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a),,,0))=0)*C$2:C$12))



The correct answer should be 13, not 10, unless I am missing something.
You can break down your formula to understand why you are getting 128.
When you multiply a horizontal vector by a vertical vector, the result is a matrix.
=TEXTSPLIT(F5,",")<>B2:B12

Result:

When you multiply that matrix by column C, you obtain:

and the sum of all those numbers is 128.
One way to do this with TEXTSPLIT is to process each row separately.
=SUM(BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(F5,",")<>B2:B12,LAMBDA(ARR,AND(ARR)))*C2:C12)
which would give the answer of 13

Hi @Ron Rosenfeld, If you take from A to K and giving each input sales as 1 and ignoring {A,D,E,H,K} then the total result would be 6. Your formula is giving result 5. Any way thank you.

I agree with you that it should be 13. Including A,D,E,H,K is the same as excluding B,C,F,E,I,J and should give the same answer.

@Srikanth You are either doing something wrong or expressing yourself incorrectly. I obtain a result of 6 by following those instructions in your comment. Perhaps you did not replace the 0 at K?

@MayukhBhattacharya NOT B,C,F,G,I,J is the same as equal to A,D,E,H,K =4+3+5+1+0 =>13.

@MayukhBhattacharya But that is not what is shown in his screenshot in his question, to which I was replying.

@RonRosenfeld Sir what you said, may be not showing but OP did explained in his post --> `If I am using the same formula for "Not Equals to" it is not giving the exact result. I stuck here what could be the reason.
=SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT(F2,",")<>B2:B12)*C2:C12)`

A very simple formula
[E2]=SUM($C$2:$C$12*ISERROR(FIND($B$2:$B$12,D2)))

fill down.

This formula easily inversible. While it counts by "Not equal to", the formula with the inverted condition counts by "Equal to":
[E2]=SUM($C$2:$C$12*NOT(ISERROR(FIND($B$2:$B$12,D2))))
or 
[E2]=SUM($C$2:$C$12*ISNUMBER(FIND($B$2:$B$12,D2)))

So, different condition expressions behave differently. Generally, always keep in mind the basic low:
NOT(AND(X,Y))=OR(NOT(X),NOT(Y))

The main logical error in your formula is that: while the task is to sum items in the list / not in the list, TEXTSPLIT(F2,",")=B2:B12 performs the revers operation to check if list's element is among items. So, TEXTSPLIT(F2,",")<>B2:B12 for each F2 list's element returns ALL items which are not equal that element.
